# Dynamic width column xaml won't work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have been trying to get dynamic column width to work for my simple WP8.1 app. The goal is to have the first column take up half of the listbox, and the other two columns a quarter each. I hoped to do this by assigning a dynamic width, using the * indicator as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465337.aspx#dynamic_layout).
This let me to the piece of xaml code at the bottom of my post.

In my MainPage I set the DataContext to an ObservableCollection, and all the data shows up in their respective columns, the columns just do not get the desired width (they are all as small as can be). 
What prevents my dynamic width from working? I have toyed around with HorizontalAlignment and Width of TextBoxes too, but with no success. I tried to look around for answers, and I even used some examples that did work, but that did not bring me closer to understanding why it does not work here.

Thanks in advance.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="transactionListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item Grid itself is being sized-to-fit by the ListBox.  You can override this behavior by setting the `ItemContainerStyle` to make the ListBoxItems stretch to fill horizontally:

```
<ListBox Name="transactionListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.
Why does this work, but for example setting the Grid to HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" doesn't?

Comment: @Clueless it's because the `ListBox` control inserts a wrapper (a `ListBoxItem` around your Grid).  The ListBox uses a `StackPanel` by default to arrange its children, which in turn is not designed to stretch-to-fill horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a constraining width on the ListBox or Grid.  With your code, the grid and ListBox will re-size to fit the content, so there is no need for the dynamic column definitions.

Comment: Your answer was correct (adjusting the width of the grid), but I picked McGarnagle's answer because it also explains how to make sure the Grid automatically stretches.